# AngularJS and Rails - e2e testacular testing . How to login user to test angular pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, tdd, angularjs, karma-runner

Here is the issue I have faced. There is the code I'm working on. Code is mostly typical MVC written in Rails with Haml view files.

One part of the app is utilizing AngularJS to do all cool MVC in the browser.

No issue here.

In order to use this part of the application user has to login and here the issue appears:

I have noticed interesting following behavior:
If I instruct my test to go and visit login(or any other) page using chrome

```
beforeEach(function() {
  browser().navigateTo('/help');
});
```

with the test that follows:

```
it('should scream for help', function() {
  expect(element('#test').text()).toMatch('Help!');
});
```

and HTML

```
<div>
  <h1>Help</h1>
  <p id="test">Help!</p>
</div>
```

What I get is the frozen browser and rest of the test is not executing. Now, the minute I add angular to the element of the website:

```
<div ng-app>
  <h1>Help</h1>
  <p id="test">Help!</p>
</div>
```

The tests run as expected (both red and green).

The problem this is causing me is that I have little to no idea how to login my user (with something like "before all" block) so that I can happily perform my tests on angular functionality.

For non-javascript things I use RSpec and Capybara where I can conveniently call sign_in user.

Does anybody know how to login user (using non-anguar pages)? Perhaps there is a better way to handle this test? I was thinking about using PhantomJS like you can see in Railscasts episode 391, but I'd like to go using tools recommended by Google. I'm not smart enough to be reinventing the wheel:).

All advice highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks very interesting question but I don't know rails. Why do you need to stich together so many testing technologies ?

Comment: I don't. I'm trying to consider using some of them if it will make sense. Since I have solved the problem however I can now tell that testacular was something I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright here is what I did (if you have better solution I'll be grateful):

1. I used testacular
2. Since login form was not "angular enabled" I added ng-app to div wrapping around the form
3. I added ng-model "login" and "password" to my input fields
4. since I had that i could use

   input('password').enter('PASSWORD GOES HERE');
5. Then just clicking on submit, et voilà.

Now, here is what was tricky:

when I wanted to execute all tests that were "meat and potatoes" of my work I got:

```
warn (proxy): Proxy Request failed - Error: socket hang up
```

I have realized that this is caused by testacular executing remaining instructions before it got response from server that user is logged in.

So I added pause(); (you can add anything you want to make it wait a little if you experience same issue)

GREEN

Answer (score 0):

basically you want to POST the user login/password to the login form in beforeEach. write a function to do so, take a look at angular-scenario.js for the browser() object.

Comment: I was considering that, what I found is that unless I have some angular content wrapping around my form in login page my testacular will completely ignore the page and not execute anything.

Comment: What I tried since I asked this question was using something like capybara-like help from poltergeist and phantomJS. It proved to be pretty slow with the application I'm working on. 

Thanks Gal for your feedback on this.